# Problem with import in Anaconda environment [Error 193]

Tags: python, windows, anaconda

I've tried to create an Anaconda environment on Windows 10 with TensorFlow. Everything went fine, I downloaded Anaconda 3.7 64-bit version for Windows and I've `pip` installed tensorflow-gpu and keras. Everything collapse during the first try to import anything.

```
import pandas as pd
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-1-7dd3504c366f>", line 1, in <module>
    import pandas as pd

  File "C:\Users\Misiek\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\__init__.py", line 13, in <module>
    __import__(dependency)

  File "C:\Users\Misiek\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\numpy\__init__.py", line 142, in <module>
    from . import core

  File "C:\Users\Misiek\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\numpy\core\__init__.py", line 23, in <module>
    WinDLL(os.path.abspath(filename))

  File "C:\Users\Misiek\Anaconda3\lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 356, in __init__
    self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)

OSError: [WinError 193] %1 is not a valid Win32 application
```

Well, I tried to reinstall Anaconda to 32 bit and everything worked fine (I could import pandas, NumPy, etc.), except pip cannot find the appropriate TensorFlow distribution... So I can imagine that I cannot use TensorFlow in the 32 bit version.

How can I fix this problem?